# What does invariance under time translation exactly mean?

Tags: oscillators, invariants

Even after a google search I didn't find a definition of the concept "invariance under time translation" used (and not defined) in my lecture notes.

Consider for example the differential equation
$$\dot{\vec{z}}(t)=A \vec{z}(t)$$
for $z \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and a time independent $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$.

It is stated that this differential equation is invariant under time translations, which supposingly means:
$$\dot{\vec{z}}(t-s)=A \vec{z}(t-s) \quad \forall s \in \mathbb{R}$$

Is this correct? If so, how can I prove that the above equation is actually invariant under time translations?

Comment: Since the hamtonian is the generator of time translations, invariance under time usually implies energy is conserved for some system. Why don't you solve the ODE and use the solution

Comment: Good idea. In the text the invariance under time translation was used to deduce some property for the propagator and from them to find the solutions, therefore I thought there must be a way to prove the property a priori to its solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dot means "derivative w.r.t. time". Thus, we use the chain rule as well as the abbreviation $t^\prime=t-s$ and write
$$
A \;x(t^\prime) =
A \;x(t-s) = 
\dot x(t-s) 
= \frac{dx(t-s)}{dt} 
= \frac{d(t-s)}{dt} \cdot \frac{dx(t^\prime)}{dt^\prime}\Big|_{t^\prime = t-s}
= \frac{dx(t^\prime)}{dt^\prime}\Big|_{t^\prime = t-s}
$$
and for $y$ and $z$ similarly. Thus, we obtained
$A \;x(t^\prime) = \frac{dx(t^\prime)}{dt^\prime}\Big|_{t^\prime = t-s}$
which is equivalent to your initial equation. Thus, the initial condition of our clock did not change the physics.